# change number of partitions in kml3d

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using the kml3d R package to cluster longitudinal data and the default function searches between 2 and 6 partitions. However I want to search between 1 and 6 partitions to explore if the best solution would be not to partition, using the Calinsky Harabatz criteria. I tried to change the nbCluster argument:

```
kml3d(devclust270, nbClusters= 2:5, toPlot = "criterion")
```

However the resulting graph continues to display between 2 and 6 partitions

Is there a solution to that?

Thanks in advance